# Dangling Participial Phrase

Tags: writing, syntactic-analysis, participles

Here’s the original:

> The veterinarian was caught off guard when, regaining consciousness,
>   we were again attacked by the cat.

My rewrite of this sentence is either:

> The veterinarian was caught off guard when we were again attacked by
>   the cat regaining consciousness.

or else:

> The veterinarian was caught off guard when, regaining consciousness, the cat attacked us.

Is either of these rewrites satisfactory?

Comment: It is a confusing sentence. It's hard to answer your question without knowing, at least for starters, who regained consciousness, the cat, the veterinarian, or "us"?

Comment: If a cat attacks, shouldn't it already have regained consciousness?

Comment: so you're saying the cat had lost consciousness, then regained consciousness, then attacked. The vet and "us" never lost consciousness in the first place -- correct? :)

Comment: Yes,that is almost what i mean .

Comment: May be i should say
"The veterinarian was caught off guard when the cat, having regained consciousness, attacked us"

Comment: @Mohammed Al-mubark: You should definitely rephrase it thus. The cat can't possibly have attacked *while* it was regaining consciousness - it could only do this *after* regaining consciousness. All other variations fail at the level of meaning, regardless of the grammar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on our exchange of comments, your third sentence is correct:

> The veterinarian was caught off guard when, regaining consciousness,
>   the cat attacked us.

Since you're trying to say that it is a second attack, I'd add "again":

> The veterinarian was caught off guard when, regaining consciousness,
>   the cat attacked us again.

Answer (score 3):

Both rewrites retain the ambiguity of the first sentence, but I'd say the latter is better.It is unclear who regained consciousness. Assuming that it's the cat, here's an alternative:

> After regaining consciousness, the cat caught the veterinarian off
>   guard by attacking us again.