# Using the gerund to express causation

Tags: gerunds, prepositional-phrases

Is the following phrase grammatically correct:

> Suffering from anxiety and depression, life has been a tremendous challenge for him ever since he was a young boy.

Comment: It's a [dangling modifier](https://writingexplained.org/grammar-dictionary/dangling-modifier) . _He_ has suffered from anxiety, so you could change it to _...he has found life a tremendous challenge..._

Comment: Is the modifier really dangling, if the pronouns it modifies (i.e. "he" and "him") are present? According to the link you provided, modifiers are only dangling if the words they modify are omitted.

Comment: The sentence as it stands implies to me that _life_ has suffered from anxiety, not _he_.

Comment: Yep - that is indeed the problem. But is it grammatically incorrect, or just a bit convoluted? Would the following addition fix it: "Suffering from anxiety and depression, his life has been a tremendous challenge, ever since he was a young boy." Or does ist require a complete rearrangement, like "Suffering from ... , he found life tremendously challenging, ever since he was a young boy".

Comment: That's the sort of rearrangement I suggested in my original comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Dangling Participles"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148766/dangling-participles) See the article by G Pullum. Some people would class this as an error, but if the meaning is clear, no less an acknowledged expert than Pullum has said that such people are high on the hyperprescriptive cline.