# Modifying a sentence object

Tags: verbs, tenses

> In one study, for instance, bar codes were placed on bees, tracking their activities.

Is this correct? Or do we say...

> In one study, for instance, bar codes were placed on bees to track their activities.

Comment: If the purpose of placing bar codes on bees was to track their activities, then your second example is correct, where the infinitival clause "to track their activities" is a purpose adjunct. Btw, I don't see a sentence object'.

Comment: The first sentence has a faulty modifier; bar codes (and placement of bar codes on bees) don't/doesn't track anything. How serious an error this is (the meaning of the sentence remains clear) is debatable. See [G Pullum's article on 'Prescriptivist Poppycock'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148766/dangling-participles/381464#381464) (though why not use the infinitive clause?)

Comment: Contrast "In one study, for instance, bar codes were placed on bees, collecting pollen from wild flowers." (You might omit the comma after bees.)

Comment: Simpler is to say: In one study bee activity was tracked by placing bar codes on the bees.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There's no modifier in the first sentence. "Tracking their activities" is a supplement, and hence not a modifier.